# wait() before next iteration in a for loop java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, wait, notify

What I'm trying to do here is to upload files one by one. For example, if my file list contains 2 files ready to upload, I want to upload the second file once the first is uploaded and created.

Actually, I loop the file list and upload the file from each iteration whitout waiting the last upload to finish.

Here is an idea of what I'm excepecting  :

```
for(FileContainerBean fileContainer:fileContainerList){

    FileUpload fileUpload=new FileUpload(fileContainer.getFile());
    Thread th=new Thread(fileUpload);
    th.start();

    //Now i want here to wait beafore moving to the next iteration

    while(!fileContainer.isCreated(){
          wait();
        }
    if(fileContainer.isCreated(){
       notify();
      }
}
```

fileContainer is a bean with getters and setters (setFile,getFile,isCreated....).

When the upload is over and the file is created ( HttpResponseCode=201), fileContainer.isCreated=true. Initially, isCreated=false;

I hope that I'm clear enough ! So is it possible to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Ismail

Comment: Where is your `synchronized` block?

Comment: I know that I need a synchronized block but I don't what to synchronize ? Should it be : synchronized(fileContainer)?

Comment: You need to synchronize on the object on which you then call `notify()` and `wait()`. In your case, you are calling `this.wait()` so you need to be `synchronized` on `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to continue the execution only after the `th` thread is finished? Just don't run it in a separate thread, but rather:

```
for(FileContainerBean fileContainer:fileContainerList){
    FileUpload fileUpload=new FileUpload(fileContainer.getFile());
    fileUpload.run();

    // continues after the file is uploaded
}
```

If you want to keep this in a separate thread after all (as you said in a comment), then execute the whole loop in the background:

```
    Runnable uploadJob = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            for(FileContainerBean fileContainer:fileContainerList){
                FileUpload fileUpload=new FileUpload(fileContainer.getFile());
                fileUpload.run();
                // continues after the file is uploaded
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(uploadJob).start();
```

Comment: This assumes that the `FileUpload.run()` is blocking (and that `run()` exists at all)

Comment: Yes, I have assumed that. It must be a `Runnable`, because the OP is creating a `Thread` out of it, so `run()` exists.

Comment: fileUpload.run() actually do exactly what I want, but it doesn't upload in Backgroud, so for a 1go file, i can't use my application while the upload is running.

Comment: Yes dziękuję ;) :D , you are 100% right  ! It's working as i want. Thank you  ! But I'm wondering how the loop is waiting until the upload is done whithout `wait()` or `notify()` ?

Comment: It's just a plain old synchronous Java code inside the loop. Each instruction "waits" for the previous one before it can execute. No magic whatsoever here.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 while(true){
     if(fileContainer.isCreated()){
       break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Well, I have `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` at `notify()`

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `notify()` in the `run` method of Thread `th` so after the new thread finish the upload, it will notify the waited thread.

Or I see that you want your main thread to wait until the upload process completed, so why don't you simply make your program single threaded.
I mean don't initiate the upload process in a new thread, because the default behavior then is wait until the current upload is finished then start the second upload and that is what you want.

Comment: I do the upload metod in a Threa so I could upload in Background. File size are very big ( 1Go 2Go 100Go .... ) , i have to run it background so i can use my application while uploading.

Comment: Okay so we will stick to the first solution then, try to put the `notify()` in the run method of the Thread `th`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis @Ahmed Hamdy. I have done this : In the for loop and before the wait(), I've added : `synchronized(this){...this.wait()...}` then in the Upload method, i do `notify()` when the upload is over. But I have `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` caused by `java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)` in the upload method, in the line : `notify`